# How to navigate to another user control by clicking a button in a usecontrol

Tags: wpf, navigation

I have a user control (UserLogin.xaml) in my MainWindow and I want to navigate to another user control (ShowPage.xaml) by clicking a button inside the UserLogin user control. And I want to do this in code.

This is my UserLogin UserControl.

```
<UserControl x:Class="bAV.UserLogin"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
          Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" 
         Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="LogIn" Name="btnlogin" Click="btnlogin_Click" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And when the button is clicked, I want to navigate to another UserControl ShowPage.xaml.

```
private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    Uri uri = new Uri("Showpage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    NavigationService ns = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
    ns.Navigate(uri);
    //here I am getting object reference not set to an instance of an object       
}
```

This is MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="bAV.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:bAV" WindowState="Maximized"> 
    <Grid>
        <my:UserLogin HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />      
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the new UserControl I want to navigate to.

```
<UserControl x:Class="bAV.Showpage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" 
         Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: improve your question, explain what you want (with code or a drawing), I don't understand what you mean by "open new usercontrol"/"navigate to usercontrol", do you mean the usercontrol is inside a Frame, and by clicking the button will navigate to a new created usercontrol?

Comment: i have one main window inside that window i called my first created usercontrol.when click the button in this usercontrol i want to open new created 2nd user control

Comment: there are many ways to do it in code. but more details are needed as how the usercontrol is implemented (so we can wire the button's Click event), and how it is added to MainWindow (what is the container to hold the usercontrol?)

Comment: In Mainwindow.xaml i have called my 1st uesrconyrol like this <window: ....>    <my:UserLogin HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" /> </window>

Comment: after that Userlogin.xaml this is usercontrol.In this usercontrol i have button.when clicking this button i want to show one more user control that is usercontrol2.xaml

Comment: the details in your comments should be added to you question, you can `edit` your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NavigationService (your attempt)**

WPF has two navigators: `NavigationWindow` and `Frame`. Only these navigators have NavigationService to navigate contents. So you first have to put  `UserLogin` inside a Frame, or you will get **null** when you call `NavigationService.GetNavigationService`.

```
<Window x:Class="bAV.MainWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:bAV" WindowState="Maximized"> 
    <Grid>
        <Frame Source="UserLogin.xaml" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Another solution without using navigation service**

Add both UserControls to MainWindow, first Showpage and then UserLogin, at first only UserLogin is visible and Showpage is hidden behind it.

```
<Window x:Class="bAV.MainWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:bAV" WindowState="Maximized"> 
    <Grid>
        <my:Showpage />
        <my:UserLogin />      
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When button is click, hide UserLogin so Showpage becomes visible.

```
private void btnlogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: Sorry..I dint understood..in mainwindow i have called usercontrol

Comment: kennyzx I attached my code as a answer 2..please check it

Comment: you don't post answer, just edit you initial post (adding what you said in your comments and adding your code). you can edit it as many times as you wish, this is how SO works.

Comment: In order to use navigationservice, you have to use `Frame` to host your login control, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Translated by Google Translate, sorry :)

Describe below a simple solution:

1. I created two UserControls: UserControl1.xaml and UserControl2.xaml
2. Inside each UserControl I created a simple feature, only to differentiate them.
3. Example: TextBox and TextBlock...
4. In MainWindow I created the following:

```html
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="0">
            <ListBoxItem Name="PrimeiraJanela" 
                         MouseUp="PrimeiraJanela_MouseUp">
              Primeira opção</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Name="SegundaJanela" 
                         MouseUp="SegundaJanela_MouseUp">
              Segunda opção</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
        <ContentControl x:Name="UserControls" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
```

5. The goal is that when you click the ListBox Item "PrimeiraJanela" the ContentControl load UserControl1, when you click the ListBoxItem "SegundaJanela" the ContentControl load UserControl2.
6. Editing the Code-Behind, do the following:

```html
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        UserControl1 user1 = new UserControl1();
        UserControl2 user2 = new UserControl2();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PrimeiraJanela_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            UserControls.Content = null;
            UserControls.Content = user1;
        }

        private void SegundaJanela_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            UserControls.Content = null;
            UserControls.Content = user2;
        }
    }
```

This is the simplest solution I know.
(I am beginner in WPF)